# HTML5 Canvas game development complication

Tags: javascript, loops, html5-canvas

I'm building a game using HTML5 canvas.

You can find it here, along with the source code: [www.techgoldmine.com](http://www.techgoldmine.com).

I'd make a jsFiddle, but in all honesty my attention span is too short (and myself mostly too stupid) to learn how it works.

I'm currently stuck at a function that looks at the positioning of certain elements on either side of the canvas and moves them so that the y-axis area they cover does not overlap. I call them turbines, but thin white rectangles would be more accurate. I suggest refreshing a few times to visually understand what's going on.

This is the function that spawns the turbines:

```
function gameStateNewLevel(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        turbine = {};
        turbine.width = 10;
        turbine.height = 150;
        turbine.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*600)
        if (Math.random()*10 > 5){
            turbine.side = leftSide;
        }else{
            turbine.side = rightSide;
        }
        turbine.render  = function (){
            context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF"
    context.fillRect(turbine.side, turbine.y, turbine.width,turbine.height);
        }
        turbine.PositionTop = turbine.y;
        turbine.PositionBottom = turbine.y + turbine.height;

        turbines.push(turbine);

    }
    context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF"       
    switchGameState(GAME_STATE_PLAYER_START);

}
```

So far I've built (with the help of you wonderful people) a function (that is part of a loop) picking out each of these turbines, and starts comparing them to one another. I'm completely stumped when it comes to understanding how I'll get them to move and stop when needed:

```
function updateTurbines(){
var l = turbines.length-1; 
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++){
    var tempTurbine1 = turbines[i];
     tempTurbine1.PositionTop = tempTurbine1.y; 
     tempTurbine1.PositionBottom = tempTurbine1.y +    tempTurbine1.height;
     for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) { 
      var tempTurbine2 = turbines[j];
      tempTurbine2.PositionTop = tempTurbine2.y;
      tempTurbine2.PositionBottom = tempTurbine2.y + tempTurbine2.height;
      if ((tempTurbine1 !== tempTurbine2) && FIXME == true){
       if(tempTurbine1.PositionBottom >=    tempTurbine2.PositionTop){
                        turbines[j].y -=2;
                                            //A while loop breaks the browser :(

                    }

                }
            }FIXME = false;
        }
}
```

Any ideas or requests for additional explanation and info are more than welcome. I also have a feeling I'm severely over complicating this. Goddamn my head hurts. Bless you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's your problem. I can only see those "turbines" lifting and then they flow out of the screen, and sometimes a turbine stays on the screen. I don't know what you mean with overlapping; could you possibly elaborate?

Comment: Sure, I added a function that spawns the turbines into the description. Their positions on the y-axis are determined automatically, and I need to make sure they're not overlapping each other when the player starts playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your code is a little bit messy do I decided to begin with a clean slate.

- Use getters/setters for `bottom` and `right`. You can calculate them given the `left`/`width` and `top`/`height` values, respectively. This will save you from altering the complementary variable `right` when modifying e.g. `left`.
- You seem to be looking for a collison detection algorithm for rectangles. This is quite easy if the rectangles have the same x-coordinate - two such rectangles do *not* collide if the bottom of the first is above the top of the other, or if the top of the first is under the bottom of the other. Use this algorithm along with a `while` loop to generate a new turbine as long as they collide.

This is what I ended up with (it's a separate piece of code as I stated, so you'll have to blend it into your game): http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/249/.

```
var ctx = $('#cv').get(0).getContext('2d');

var Turbine = function(left, top, width, height) {
    this.left = left;
    this.top = top;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
};

Object.defineProperties(Turbine.prototype, {
    bottom: {
        get: function() {
            return this.top + this.height;
        },
        set: function(v) {
            this.top = v - this.height;
        }
    },
    right: {
        get: function() {
            return this.left + this.width;
        },
        set: function(v) {
            this.left = v - this.width;
        }
    }
});

var turbines = [];

function turbineCollides(tn) {
    for(var i = 0; i < turbines.length; i++) {
        var to = turbines[i];
        // they do not collide if if one's completely under
        // the other or completely above the other
        if(!(tn.bottom <= to.top || tn.top >= to.bottom)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false; // this will only be executed if the `return true` part
                  // was never executed - so they the turbine does not collide
}

function addTurbine() {
    var t, h;

    do { // do while loop because the turbine has to be generated at least once

        h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
        t = new Turbine(0, h, 15, 100);

    } while(turbineCollides(t));

    turbines.push(t);
}

// add two of them (do not add more than 4 because they will always collide
// due to the available space! In fact, there may be no space left even when
// you've added 2.)
addTurbine();
addTurbine();

function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";

    for(var i = 0; i < turbines.length; i++) {
        var turbine = turbines[i];
        ctx.fillRect(turbine.left, turbine.top,
                     turbine.width, turbine.height);
    }
}

draw();​
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Being a complete noob, this may as well be another language to me. It will take me a while to figure out, but it certainly looks promising. I'll get back to you when I can. Cheers!